# in-app facebook authorization - similar to tinder

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I have followed the facebook SDK tutorials to incorporate a Log In button into my ios iphone application, it opens up a web browser, and asks me to log in. I have noticed that other applications do a more 'in-app' seamless log in to facebook accounts. ONe example of which is tinder, below is the exact flow of what happens in tinder:

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

3:

[image]

4:

[image]

Done

How can I achieve this behaviour? I want the authorization to happen like it does with tinder, without having to swap to a browser to get the log in token?

Can somebody please tell me how I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to integrate Facebook iOS SDK and set proper `loginBehavior` of the login manager.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *mgr = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
mgr.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
[mgr logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_email"] 
                      handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error){
                          // handle login result here
                      }];
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKLoginManager/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the advice, unfortunately it still redirects to a different page where I always have to click "ok", see screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/LSjhA9r.png  I'm using permissions "public_profile" by the way.

Comment: Sorry, you are right! It's because I'm running the application from simulator ( which doesn't have facebook installed ). Thank you for helping me, marking your answer as accepted.